# critical temperature and critical pressure condition data of Starch (Corn)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

does anyone know where can I find the critical temperature and critical pressure condition data of Starch (Corn)?

Comment: Can't find non-existent things.

Comment: @Mithoron The OP confidence that it exists is worthy of my admiration. I suspect he may have become a victim of a joke of "go and find it."

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetical temperature of starch melting or even boiling is much higher than temperature of starch pyrolysis, not speaking about critical values.

Additionally, starch is mixture of molecules of various lengths and branching. Therefore, melting, boiling nor critical parameters would not have been defined, even if starch had been thermally stable.